# Refresh Issue? Script keeps running on every refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, file, page-refresh

Every time refresh is press it is deleting my txt out of the file. I only need this script to be ran every time a player has won on my game. But yet it seems to run every refresh.

Here is the index

```
<?php
    $win = 0;
    $cards = 5;
    $probability = 0.5;

    function generateScratchCard($n,$p) {
        $w = 0;
        for($i = 0; $i<$n; $i++) {
            $result = (mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax());
            if($result >= $p) {
                $w++;
            }
        }
        return $w;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/scratch.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            <?php
                $win = generateScratchCard($cards, $probability);
                echo "var win = ".$win."; ";
                echo "var cards = ".$cards."; ";
            ?>
            var p = 0.5;
            var scratched = 0;

            function callback(d) {
                scratched++;
                if(scratched >= cards) {
                    if(win > (cards/2)) {
                        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<?php include_once ("file.php"); ?>';
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'You lose, but you can try again!';
                    }
                }
            }

            //+ Function written by Jonas Raoni Soares Silva
            //@ http://jsfromhell.com/array/shuffle [v1.0]
            function shuffle(o){ //v1.0
                for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
                return o;
            };

            window.onload = function() {

                var container = document.getElementById('container');
                var cardsArray = [];
                for(var i=0, l=cards; i<l; i++) {
                    if(i<win) {
                        cardsArray[i] = true;
                    } else {
                        cardsArray[i] = false;
                    }
                }
                shuffledArray = shuffle(cardsArray);
                for(var i=0; i<cards; i++) {
                    var scratchCard = document.createElement('div');
                    var backgroundImage;
                    if(shuffledArray[i]) {
                        backgroundImage = 'assets/images/win.png';
                    } else {
                        backgroundImage = 'assets/images/lose.png';
                    }

                    container.appendChild(scratchCard);
                    createScratchCard({
                        'container':scratchCard,
                        'background':backgroundImage,
                        'foreground':'assets/images/foreground.png',
                        'percent':40,
                        'coin':'assets/images/coin2.png',
                        'thickness':18,
                        'counter':'percent',
                        'callback':'callback'
                    });
                }


            };
        </script>
        <style>
            #container { margin: 50px auto; width: 900px; }
            #container div { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; }
            #result { font-size: 15px; text-align: center; color: #514d4d; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold; padding: 15px 0 15px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the file.php

```
<?php
$coupons = file("coupons.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
echo "Your Winning Code Is: ".htmlspecialchars($coupons[0]).".";
array_shift($coupons); // Removes the first coupon
file_put_contents("coupons.txt", implode("\n", $coupons));
?>
```

Thank you for helping :)

[sample here](http://510vapour.com/files/tyler/SCRATCHNVAPE/scratchphp/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you include the PHP file directly in the body of your HTML, it will be printed out and executed during the page load every time. Nature of the beast. In order to trigger a PHP file based on a Javascript event, you need ajax. This assumes the [jQuery library to handle ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), since rolling your own is a bit labor-intensive. Here's a quick way to include jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And here's the callback function:

```
   function callback(d) {
        scratched++;
        if(scratched >= cards) {
            if(win > (cards/2)) {
                $.ajax({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: "file.php"
                })
                .done(function( msg ) {
                    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = msg;
                });
            } else {
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'You lose, but you can try again!';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No problem. If you could upvote and accept my answer, I'd appreciate it.